# How to show All (product) Categories List in admin side: Magento

Tags: magento, module, admin, categories

I want to show All Product Categories in admin side of My module in System.xml as a multiselect.

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($_category->entity_id);
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');

foreach($collection as $cat){
    if($_category->getIsActive()){
         $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());                       
         $helper->getCategoryUrl($cat);
         echo $cat->getName();
    } 
}
```

But it will not show what i am want, i want only product categories.... Can some one idea about it... Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show Category selection in system configuration,i have find a solution for it by extending a Mage Model class and method.

`Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Category`

and remove the line.

```
->addPathFilter('^1/[0-9]+$')
```

Now it display multiselect option in system configuration. Where you can select multi categories from the list..

Answer (score 2):

I was working on Magento 1.7 and I didn't see a line that contains
    ->addPathFilter('^1/[0-9]+$')

But, removing a following line worked for me.
    ->addRootLevelFilter()

Comment: Looks like they changed the regex to an actual function in 1.7. That function does the same thing, so just do what Nahid did and comment that line out.

Answer (score 1):

```
?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>

<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo "<b>".$_category->getName(). $_category->getId()."</b>" ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo "--".$_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```